# Expanded Cell not being clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my app i have a `tableview` with a custom cell which contains a `collectionview` and a `button` in it.I want to implement expanded functionality in my app.The issue is that when the expand a paticular cell, the collectionview data and button are not being clicked.I found out that when i fixed the table height, my collectionview and buttons are getting clicked but when i calculate the expanded height and assign it to tableview at that time its not being clicked.

Code

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourBudgetTableViewCell

             cell.budgetIcon.image = UIImage(named: "ic_your_budget_close");

           // cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row;

          //  cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)

            cell.selected=true;

            isCellSelected = indexPath.row;

            self.tableView.beginUpdates();

            self.tableView.endUpdates();

        }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourBudgetTableViewCell

            cell.budgetIcon.image = UIImage(named: "ic_your_budget_expand");

            isCellSelected = -1;

            self.tableView.beginUpdates();

            self.tableView.endUpdates();



        }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {



        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!



        if selectedCell.selected {

            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false);

            self.tableView(self.tableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

            return nil;

        }



        return indexPath

    }



     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {



            if isCellSelected == indexPath.row

            {

                return 200;

            }

            else

            {

                return 44;

            }

           // return 200;  

        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



            return self.listBudget.count

        }
```

So if i give fixed height say 200 in heightForRowAtIndexPath the click works fine, but if not given fixed click is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check for the height for the expended cell or set alternate background color to cell. You will see that cell does not have that height which is required to display CollectionView. Because of that you are not able to click on the buttons at bottom of cell.

Comment: i can see the button also i am not able to click the collectionview cell also

Comment: Set a property to your cell clipToBounds to YES and let me know if you can still see the buttons.

Comment: nah still cannot click :(

Comment: Check for height of expended cell, is it enough which required ?

Comment: yep expanded ka funda is proper

Comment: I tried cell.contentView,clipsToBounds=true,my collection view and button is not visible i.e. content view is not getting update after expand, how can i fix this??

Comment: That means the calculated height for the row of table after expend, is not same as required. So check your concept behind providing height or paste  in your question to check.